# What's the purpose of the 'download' file which is downloaded by the browser when I make a request to 'localhost:3306'?

Tags: mysql, browser, localhost

just a question. I have tried to open the browser and make a request to my local server on the mysql default port (3306) and unexpectedly the browser downloaded a 'download' file. I looked inside of it and found infos about about my server version, some binary stuff and this: 'mysql_native_password' between some binary text.

Should I worry about something? What is that file for???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling the browser to download a page through a mysql connection. The browser sends a request, and mySQL does not understand it (because it expects its own protocol, not HTTP), so it answers with a list of capabilities told in its own protocol (some binary jitter). The browser gets this response and because it is not correctly identified as a webpage (remember, the response is not HTTP) it cannot assume better than to offer it as a file, so it says this is the unnamed file "download" and puts the response into that. That's what you see. You're forcing a chinese into a conversation with a french ... don't expect sane results ;)

Comment: Thanks, but is it a reason to take some actions or something? Or should I do nothing?

Comment: Sorry I did not state clearly that this is a standard answer, so you don't need to do anything about it. "mysql_native_password" is the name of the login mechanism the server expects the client to use. Details of the response: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html